# Syntax error while using python trace

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, trace

I'm running a script of which I need to see which statements of whichever files it touches. So, I'm using Python's `trace`.

This command runs perfectly on the linux terminal: `/x/eng/bbsvl/users/nikhilh/C4563855_4563855_1710110159/test/nate/bin/ntest -noconsole NATE_HOSTS=/u/smoke/presub/tharnhosts/temp_remove/nikhilh NODES=p8020-5 /x/eng/bbsvl/users/nikhilh/C4563855_4563855_1710110159/test/lib/pynacl/ontap/test/cluster_ha.thpy`

In another cluster_ha_original.py script I've this code:

```
import trace
cmd_to_run = '/x/eng/bbsvl/users/nikhilh/C4563855_4563855_1710110159/test/nate/bin/ntest -noconsole NATE_HOSTS=/u/smoke/presub/tharnhosts/temp_remove/nikhilh NODES=p8020-5 /x/eng/bbsvl/users/nikhilh/C4563855_4563855_1710110159/test/lib/pynacl/ontap/test/cluster_ha.thpy'

tracer = trace.Trace(count=False, trace=True)

tracer.run(cmd_to_run)
r = tracer.results()
r.write_results(summary=True)
```

The above cluster_ha_original.py file should have given me the complete trace which includes the files, functions and statements which `cluster_ha.thpy` internally calls but I'm getting a syntax error:

```
[nikhilh@cycl02 test]$ python3 cluster_ha_original.py
--- modulename: trace, funcname: _unsettrace
trace.py(78):         sys.settrace(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cluster_ha_original.py", line 6, in <module>
    tracer.run(cmd_to_run)
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/trace.py", line 501, in run
    self.runctx(cmd, dict, dict)
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/trace.py", line 509, in runctx
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1
    /x/eng/bbsvl/users/nikhilh/C4563855_4563855_1710110159/test/nate/bin/ntest -noconsole NATE_HOSTS=/u/smoke/presub/tharnhosts/temp_remove/nikhilh NODES=p8020-5 /x/eng/bbsvl/users/nikhilh/C4563855_4563855_1710110159/test/lib/pynacl/ontap/test/cluster_ha.thpy
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The `trace` module traces the execution of *Python statements or expressions*.  It has no idea what to do with an arbitrary terminal command!

Comment: I think it does. I'd done this once in the past in the same scenario and unfortunately I lost those changes and I don't remember what I did :(

Comment: If it helps, the entire structure on which the cluster_ha.thpy runs is in Python